# read_stream, lamest permission ever made

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

I've seen WAY to many of these questions. Finally posting this after days of frustration.

Someone at facebook needs to work this out please.

Why should the read_stream permission prevent us from viewing a simple link with image and description in a group? It's not a shared link or anything special, just a simple link to a website and it won't show in the feed. It's my group and my Post?
Example: http://feedthemsocial.com/facebook-group-feed-demo/

And good luck getting your app approved for the read_stream... I don't get it. I just want to use the app to show my group feed, not trying to access any other information. Just simply mirroring what is in the group.

[image: custom facebook group]

IMPORTANT NOTE: I can go into any facebook page and post the same link and I'll be able to see the image and description just fine through my custom feed. No readme_stream required.

[image]

Comment: You don't need read_stream approved to show your group feed. As long as you ask your self for that permission you are fine

Comment: Awesome! How do I approve myself for that permission?

Comment: It is already done. You don't need to do anything

Comment: for a group feed you need user_groups, not read_stream. but you will not get it approved for simple websites, only for platforms without a native facebook client. but you can use that permission for everyone with a role in your app (admin, dev, tester).

Comment: @luschn when testing only the permission user_groups in the graph api it fails to show the links image and description. You must have read_stream.

Comment: @WizKid You say it's already done but the app is not in my list of apps in my profile area? What step am I missing. A more step by step answer would be great here.

Comment: well, that is probably because the link is only visible for friends, and if you can´t read the stream, you can´t read stuff from your friends. not sure, but it would be an explanation. in general, you don´t need read_stream afaik.

Comment: anyway, you just need to authorize yourself with the permission(s). no approval needed if it´s only for you. approval !== authorization.

Comment: user_groups is NOT enough to get links from a group. I even tried it using the graph api tool. Try this link, although it may expire in an hour or so... if it does just try this group id 145634995501895 and just check user_groups and the permission and you will see it FAIL. Then do a test removing user_groups and just adding read_stream and you will see it work. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=169807129831539%3Ffields%3Dfeed&version=v2.1

Comment: To any one else having this issue a Bug has been submitted and approved for a fix by the FB development team, we'll see how it goes. Answer to follow once patched.